# String compression and decompression

Tags: compression

I am working in a project with an industrial system that implements its own data storage. Some fields only allow 31 characters.

Is there any `compression / decompression` algorithm to convert a large string into a shorter string and still be able to undo the process?

I'd like the compressed result to be a string.

i.e.

> original string: "**this is a large string containing a lot of
>   characters**"
>
> compressed: "**thssalrgestrgcntniglotfchrctrs**"

Comment: It doesn't sound to me like string compression is the answer to this problem. Doesn't the storage system allow user-configurable fields?

Comment: Check `smaz` library. It might help:
https://github.com/antirez/smaz

Comment: `smaz` might be what I'm looking for